# ORA-12518, TNS: listener could not hand off client connection

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a virtual machine with virtualbox on my Mac OS X, and using SQL Developer to connect to my database. But I always get the error :

> ORA-12518, TNS: listener could not hand off client connection

While all my oracle services are running. This does not happen when the virtual machine is running on a Windows.

Comment: could be memory issues https://community.oracle.com/thread/516403?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I'm using 4 CPU and 8GB+ RAM so it isn't memory issues

Comment: What happens when you connect with SQLPlus on the VM?